# Storage pool disappeared after added one disk on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, storage, storage-spaces

the system, windows 10 pro, works fine in the last few months. After I just added the second disk, the storage space panel shows unrecognized configuration. I restarted the system and everything disappeared, nothing shown on the storage panel, disk management as well expect the system disk. i can't create a new pool and the physical disks are normally shown on the device manager. I have tried everything I can but nothing works except one command:

get-storagepool

```
FriendlyName OperationalStatus HealthStatus IsPrimordial IsReadOnly     Size AllocatedSize

------------ ----------------- ------------ ------------ ----------     ---- -------------

Primordial   OK                Healthy      True         False      32.81 TB      32.75 TB

Get-PhysicalDisk 

Number FriendlyName  SerialNumber MediaType   CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage          Size 
------ ------------  ------------ ---------   ------- ----------------- ------------ -----          ---- 
5      QEMU HARDDISK QM00009      Unspecified False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown     7.28 TB 
2      QEMU HARDDISK QM00003      Unspecified False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown     1.82 TB 
0      QEMU HARDDISK QM00001      Unspecified False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select   64 GB 
3      QEMU HARDDISK QM00005      Unspecified False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown     3.64 TB 
6      QEMU HARDDISK QM00011      Unspecified False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown     7.28 TB 
8      QEMU HARDDISK QM00015      Unspecified False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown     7.28 TB 
4      QEMU HARDDISK QM00007      Unspecified False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown     3.64 TB 
7      QEMU HARDDISK QM00013      Unspecified False   {Starting, OK}    Unknown      Unknown     1.82 TB
```

the other commands I tried:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> repair-VirtualDisk

cmdlet Repair-VirtualDisk at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
FriendlyName[0]: Primordial
FriendlyName[1]:
repair-VirtualDisk : No MSFT_VirtualDisk objects found with property 'FriendlyName' equal to 'Primordial'.  Verify the
value of the property and retry.
At line:1 char:1
+ repair-VirtualDisk
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Primordial:String) [Repair-VirtualDisk], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_FriendlyName,Repair-VirtualDisk

PS C:\Windows\system32> repair-VirtualDisk -friendlyname 'Storage space'
repair-VirtualDisk : No MSFT_VirtualDisk objects found with property 'FriendlyName' equal to 'Storage space'.  Verify
the value of the property and retry.
At line:1 char:1
+ repair-VirtualDisk -friendlyname 'Storage space'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Storage space:String) [Repair-VirtualDisk], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_FriendlyName,Repair-VirtualDisk

PS C:\Windows\system32> get-VirtualDisk
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-storagepool -isprimordial 0
get-storagepool : No MSFT_StoragePool objects found with property 'IsPrimordial' equal to 'False'.  Verify the value
of the property and retry.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-storagepool -isprimordial 0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (False:Boolean) [Get-StoragePool], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_IsPrimordial,Get-StoragePool
```

Since the data is kind of crucial, the resiliency type is two-way mirror. I also tried to connect to other computers but nothing changed. So what can I do?

Comment: I'm unfortunately in the same boat. Initially setup a 7 disk array with 2 disk parity redundancy. Other than being very slow (20-30MB/s), it seemed to work fine, until I added an 8th disk. Which seemed fine initially, and started optimizing. I needed to restart the machine so I stopped the optimization process and shutdown normally. When the machine came up again the pool was gone! ALL the disks seem to be in a  {Starting, OK} - Health Unknown state. I suspect they all disconnected together. I Connected the drives to another machine, with the same result. Seems like this tech isn't ready yet.